# Prove for all reals: $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 2(a+b+c)-3$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

#### Problem:

> Prove this for all reals $a,b,c$:
>
> $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 2(a+b+c)-3$$

#### Attempt:

I am trying to work backwards.
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 2(a+b+c)-3$$
$$(a+b+c)^2\geq 2(a+b+c)-3 + 2(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$(a+b+c)^2-2(a+b+c)\geq 2(ab+bc+ca)-3  $$
$$(a+b+c)(a+b+c-2)\geq 2(ab+bc+ca)-3  $$

I am stuck here. And need hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is equivalent to $$(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2\geq 0%$$

Comment: Oh! How could I forget it! Thanks!

Comment: hm remember that $x^2\geq0$ is always true for a real number

Comment: if you have another inequality?

Comment: No, currently, this is the only one I wanted to ask.

Comment: hm i will try it on MathLinks