# $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 3$ for $a+b+c\geq 3$

Tags: inequality

#### Problem:

> Prove: $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 3$ for $a+b+c\geq 3$ and $a,b,c\geq0$

#### Attempt:

I tried a simple method that $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 3$ can occur in two ways:

1. Either of $a,b,c \geq \sqrt{3}$.
2. All of $a,b,c \geq 1$

The case of all $a,b,c \leq 1$ can't occur since that means $a+b+c\geq 3$ cannot hold.

#### Question:

Are there other better methods to prove this inequality?

Comment: Just use the inequality from your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561923/prove-for-all-reals-a2b2c2-geq-2abc-3). $a,b,c$ can be any real numbers.

$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 2(a+b+c)-3\ge 2\cdot 3-3=3$$

Comment: @user236182 Exactly! but there are so many inequalities given in my book, i am not sure if i can remember all of them :(

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge \frac{(a\cdot 1+b\cdot 1+c\cdot 1)^2}{1^2+1^2+1^2}\ge \frac{3^2}{3}=3$.

Comment: @user236182 i have heard of this one, but can't use since it is given later in the chapter. Though I agree it makes the calculation very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq\frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2+(a^2+b^2)+(b^2+c^2)+(c^2+a^2))\\\geq\frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca)=\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2\geq3$

Note that $a^2+b^2\geq2ab$ as $a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2\geq0$. Apparently, it seems that $a,b,c\geq0$ is not required.

Comment: The sum of squares would just get bigger if one or two of a,b,c were negative